# How to post process with a dynamically created Google Chart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, asp.net-core, google-visualization

I have a chart that looks like this:

[image: Stacked Bar Chart]

Data comes from a web service and I want all the data to remain intact as it comes through to my model.  The bars on the chart represent timespans (just a number column that displays the timespan.TotalHours).

Occasionally, as shown in the image, a time span will be negative - meaning it was ahead of schedule.  When this is the case, I do not want to display that segment at all and in fact would like to subtract that time from the green segment.  From what I've looked up, something that could help me with the actual subtraction of the negative number could be post processing.  But how would I be able to modify my chart creation after that's done?

In case it's relavent, the code for the chart's creation is below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); 

            // Since every row will alwyas have this as the first column, we do not need to iterate. The first column will always be this title.
            data.addColumn("string", "Category"); 

            // This iterates through each stage (timespan) and creates a column for it.  
            // And display only the relavent time spans on the chart.
            @foreach (var stage in Model.selectedForm.rows[0].stages) 
            {
                @Html.Raw("data.addColumn('number', '" + Regex.Replace(stage.label, "(\\B[A-Z])", " $1") + "');") // Adding a numeric column for each timespan (stage) in that row. Using Regex to make the labels more friendly to the user.
            }


            @foreach (var row in Model.selectedForm.rows)
            {
                @Html.Raw("data.addRow(['" + row.label + "'") //The first part of our row is the label - each subsequent stage will be filled in at each iteration below

                foreach (var stage in row.stages) //For each stage in the row being created ...
                {

                    if (stage.timespan.TotalHours <= 0)
                    {
                        @Html.Raw(", " + "null") // replace the column with a null value
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.Raw(", " + stage.timespan.TotalHours) //...Continue the HTML builder adding additional timespans to eventually...
                    }
                }

                @Html.Raw("]);\n\n") //...close it here
            }

            var options = {
                titlePosition: 'none',
                width: 1200,
                height: 400,
                legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
                bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
                isStacked: true
            }

            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('SOPChart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
```

**Edit:** I've added a check in my code that generates the table to account for the negative value and not drawing the purple segment.  However there is still **the matter of subtracting that time from the previous segment** which I am unclear on how to accomplish.

**Edit:** Added the updated code with comments.  Also added an updated image of what this produces.  Now that the actual chart is being handled, I still need a way to subtract the value off of the previous (green) segment.  After this edit, here is what the chart looks like now:[image: Chart example 2]

Comment: recommend adding "if condition" within `foreach (var stage in row.stages)` -- output replacement value instead of `stage.timespan.TotalHours`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If the value in the last created column is negative (that's the only column that can be negative), I don't want to draw the last column at all and instead subtract the value from the previous one.  Hopefully that clears it up a bit.

Comment: where is the updated code?

Comment: Hey @WhiteHat I've added updated code and an updated image.  I still have not been able to find how to subtract the value of the bar that gets removed from the previous segment.  I've looked into post processing since that seems to be something that can help here, but so far have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to try javascript on the client to correct the issue...

remove the last edit and allow the negative value to come thru

then use following snippet to correct, add just above --> `var options = {`

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
  if (data.getValue(i, data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1) < 0) {
    // subtract from next to last column
    data.setValue(i, data.getNumberOfColumns() - 2, data.getValue(i, data.getNumberOfColumns() - 2) + data.getValue(i, data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1));
    // remove negative from last column
    data.setValue(i, data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1, null);
  }
}
```